# Image of $(u,w)\to u-v$ is

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $U,W$ be the subspaces of a vector space $V$. The map of $U\times W: \to V$ is given by: $(u,w)\to u-v$
>
> Show that the image of this linear map is $U+W$.

This the only question on this exercise I cannot prove.

**Question**:

**1)** How is $U+W$ the image?

**2)** How can I prove it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean $u-w$?

Comment: Yes, I do. It is stated that way in the book

Comment: You need to show that for $(u,w)\in U\times W$, we always have $u-w\in U+W$, and you need to show that for every $v\in U+W$, there exists $(u,w)\in U\times W$ with $u-w=v$.
Neither of these steps should present any difficulties beyond writing down what you want and what is given.

Comment: If you write out the full definition of $U+W$, I think it might help you answer your question(s). So, can you add the full definition of $U+V$   to the above? Edit - or it might help you understand the hints now on this page

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$w\in W \Rightarrow -w \in W$ and $u - w =u+(-w)$.

Can you use this to show that $Im(\phi) \subset U+W$, where $\Phi$ is your map?

Don't forget to check the reciprocal inclusion (it's very similar) !

Comment: As $u\in U$ and $w\in W$ so it $-w\in W$ because W is a vector space. Since $-w\in W$ so $-w\in U+W$ so $u-w\in U+W$ which means $Im(\phi)\subset U+W$, right? But this does not prove $U+W$ to be the image, right? That would require $Im(\phi)= U+W$, right?

Comment: Everything in your comment is correct, now you just need to show that $U+W\subset Im(\Phi)$. Start with let $x\in U+W$, then $\exists u\in U, v\in V,s.t. x=u+v$... and it's in no way harder than what you have already done.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the map. We have to show that $Im(f)=U+W$.
A standard way to show that two sets $A, B$ are the same set is to proove that $A \subset B$ and $A \supset B$.

- $Im(f) \subset U+W$
  $v \in Im(f) \Longleftrightarrow \exists (u,w) \in U \times W : v=f(u,w)=u-w \in U+W.$
- $U+W \subset Im(f)$
  $v \in U+W \Longleftrightarrow \exists(\lambda, \mu) \in K^2: v=\lambda u+ \mu w=(\lambda u, -\mu w) \in Im(f).$